# Keep selected value of drop down list after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, browser-refresh

I have a button to filter a list based on the selections from several drop-down values. However I am running into an issue whereby once the button is clicked, the page refreshes and the drop-down values are reset to the default. How could I ensure that after the refresh, the selected values persist on the drop-down?

```
<div><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

   <select>
    <option value="ford">ford</option>
    <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="ram">Ram</option>
    <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
   </select>

   <button id="button" onclick="filterMyList()">Filter</button>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions on how this could be handled? Thanks.

Comment: You can either go with cookies or the html5 local storage API

Comment: The script that creates the page can add the `SELECTED` attribute to the options that it used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML5 localStorage api (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Example for your case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // On refresh check if there are values selected
    if (localStorage.selectVal) {
            // Select the value stored
        $('select').val( localStorage.selectVal );
    }
});

// On change store the value
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem('selectVal', currentVal );
});
```

Hope this helps. Keep me posted.

Comment: Could you show me the code you tried so I can see why it backfires?

Comment: can you  answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631167/retain-the-dropdown-value-after-the-page-is-refresh-or-move-to-another-page-in-a/43631420#43631420

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. Further, didn't know about localStorage... very interesting! Andrei CACIO