# How to stay unchanged selected value after onchange event?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have my code like this:

```
 -- Select Banks --

 @foreach($wallet_name as $wallet_names)
 {{ $wallet_names->wallet_name }} ( $ {{ $wallet_names -> currencies['name'] 
 }} )
 @endforeach
```

whenever I choose option value , at next page select box goes back to `-- Select Banks --` always.
How can I retain the index value of the option that I selected previously.
For Example when I select A Bank: after reloading, the select box should be A Bank.

Thanks. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171840/keep-selected-value-of-drop-down-list-after-page-refresh

Comment: Please provide more detail, what did you do to go to next page?

Comment: Thanks I already got it.